# Task parallel library , release build and out of memory exception

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, memory-management, task-parallel-library

I have a piece of code that itrates over a 2 GB PDF, extracts information and using this piece of code inserts into a DB.

```
for( int i = 0 ; i < the length of the file ; i++)
{
  read something 

  Task t = new Task(() => Update(newmerch), TaskCreationOptions.PreferFairness);
                            t.Start();

}
```

When I run this code in release mode, I am getting an out of memory exception, while in debug build it works fine.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you really trying to create 2 000 000 000 `Task`s?

Comment: `Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.` I think that if you have a 2 GB PDF, you should probably rethink your data storage. You should probably store data in a format that's easier to work with.